# Add string to wordpress navigation url

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm trying to add google analytics's campaign tracker code to a menu in wordpress. Is there a place in nav-menu-template.php to add a string after the url?

Ex: http://www.page.com?utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WordPress menu, you can add query strings by using the custom link feature in the Menu section of Admin (Under Appearance => Menus).

Instead of using the page for the menu item, insert your full URL (including query string) in the custom links box and whatever you want for anchor text for the label.

That way you don't have to do something messy like mess with the core files :).